# Spring JavaMailSender - best way to use session

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mail-server

What's the best way to reuse sessions in Spring JavaMailSender?

In a scenario where a consumer reads messages from a queue and trigger emails based on the messages, the emails will be send one after the other. If a new session is created everytime, isn't that an overhead? If JavaMailSender is a singleton bean, does it use the same session always? What's the best solution here?

I saw samples of JNDI sessions being set in to JavaMailSender bean configuration. We don't have support for JNDI, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard `JavaMailSender` for the `MailSendingMessageHandler`, so you just reuse the `Session`!

```
// Check transport connection first...
if (transport == null || !transport.isConnected()) {
...
try {
    transport = connectTransport();
}

...

Transport transport = getTransport(getSession());
transport.connect(getHost(), getPort(), username, password);
return transport;

...

public synchronized Session getSession() {
    if (this.session == null) {
        this.session = Session.getInstance(this.javaMailProperties);
    }
    return this.session;
}
```

Not sure from where you heard that a new session is created for each message...

Comment: I am currently creating a new instance of JavaMailSenderImpl, hence the new session. Even though the message is read from a queue, the mail sending part is not integrated with spring integration. It's a stand alone component using JavaMailSenderImpl and MimeMessageHelper, which could get invoked from anywhere in the application for sending a mail. If we convert it in to a bean, and use it across, how does the session work? Does any mail send at any point of time use the same session?

Comment: Yes, `JavaMailSender` must be a singleton bean and its session will be reused. Only a new session will be obtained when the previous is dead. Session is a thread-safe object, so it can be shared. Nothing to worry about!